# Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component vs2010 to 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2019

i have a c# project.I writed on visual studio 2010, but now i should start with visual studio 2019. When i want to open any form design or anything, i see this error message.

i deleted .vs folder but did not work.

thank you for all helping.

[image]

Comment: what is your current project winform or wpf? Based on your error, you can try to find the  the csproj.user files, remove it and rebuild the project to check if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I rebuilt the "forms". I imported old ".cs" and "design" files. my problem is solved. I don't know if there is another way